# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined methodFacebookRequest::execute()

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm having the same error while I'm trying to get ratings of a page using php graph API. I'm making graph api call, and it's giving me a fatal error.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
require_once DIR . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php'; 
use Facebook\FacebookRequest; 
$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/{page-id}/ratings' ); 
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject(); 
var_dump($graphObject);
?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb_reviews\sdk\index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb_reviews\sdk\index.php on line 11.

Comment: which package you are using?

Comment: The class doesn’t have such a method in the v5 version of the SDK. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookRequest#instance-methods